# Carcular formulas Vb

Tags: vb.net, vb6

Tengo unas formulas en una variable de tipo string, las formulas son por ejemplo de la forma: (a+b)/(c*d)

necesito realizar estas operaciones pero no se como, debo hacer esto en visual basic

Comment: Hola, entiendo que las letras tendrás que reemplazarlas en algún momento con números, pero para realizar la operación, busca en Google *vb.net Eval* a ver si te puede servir

Answer (score 0):

Espero te sirva

agragar un boton al form.

Ejemplo para vb6:

```
Option Explicit
Dim a, b, c, d As Variant
Dim resu As Variant

Private Sub Command1_Click()
a = 15
b = 25
c = 10
d = 5

resu = (a + b) / (c * d)

MsgBox "El resultado es: " & resu


End Sub
```